# DI exception for IndentityServer4 after install core 2.1 SDK

Tags: identityserver4

I'm getting the following exception when trying to run a project produced with the `is4admin` dotnet new command.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service
>   'IdentityExpress.Manager.BusinessLogic.Interfaces.Services.ILicenseService'
>   from root provider.    at
>   Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteValidator.ValidateResolution(Type
>   serviceType, ServiceProvider serviceProvider)

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a problem not with identity server but with the AdminUI https://www.identityserver.com/products/ Likely their code needs to be updated, you can contact support and let them know.